# bwconncomp() function not working in simulink but does work in matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have written a snippet of code including the function bwconncomp() that works perfectly on my computers matlab. However, when the code was put into a simulink block on a different pc (running same version) I received an error

> Dot notation on function call return value not allowed.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0J5g.png)

When I try adding an extra line where I call the function and than dot notation choosing the item i want after I still receive an error. Do you know what might be going wrong?

```
function [cleaned_matrix] = pathFindingV2(matrix)

% find height and width of matrix to be cleaned
[HEIGHT,WIDTH] = size(matrix);

% Finds each cluster where a cluster is defined as a blob of trues that
% are connected to eachother
clusters = bwconncomp(matrix, 4).PixelIdxList;

% Choose largest cluster as main path
mainClusterIdxs = [];
maxLength = 0;

for k=1:length(clusters)
    if length(clusters{k}) > maxLength
       maxLength =  length(clusters{k});
       mainClusterIdxs = clusters{k};
    end
end

% Convert index list to a matrix form
length1 = HEIGHT * WIDTH;
cleaned_matrix = zeros(length1, 1);
cleaned_matrix(mainClusterIdxs) = 1;     
cleaned_matrix = reshape(cleaned_matrix, [HEIGHT, WIDTH]);
```

end

The algorithm above (works in matlab not simulink) takes in a matrix and finds and keeps the largest cluster and sets all other cells to 0.

Any help will be appreciated, I have been banging my head on the wall for hours

Comment: `bwconncomp(matrix, 4).PixelIdxList` is only legal since R2020a or R2020b. Is it possible that the system where you run Simulink has an older version of MATLAB?

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, both computers are running the same version so its not the problem :(. In the end I just wrote my own version of the function.